# Add button to default D7 view

Tags: views

Is there a way to add a selection button or a check box to the display of a default view? I am hoping to catch the node information of the selected row into a bucket or into a container. Below is the screen shot of my default view, I need to add the button or check box at the end of the 'Treatment' column. I have little understanding about the hook_views_default_views_alter(hoping that its implementation is relevant in this case) but not sure how a button could be added using it. Let me know if the question needs more clarification or any additional information is required.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this drupal.org documentation page called [How to add a column with dynamically generated action buttons in a View](https://www.drupal.org/node/1517916). `hook_views_default_views_alter` has essentially nothing to do with this task. Optionally an easier path is like Rules with Views Bulk Operations if you can live with like a checkbox per row, and a dropdown for the operation selection.

The more custom a look, or outside of Drupal's default behavior you deviate. The more work you have to do.